# Icon with overhead label - how to get both to respond to hover, with CSS?

Tags: css, hyperlink, hover, icons, label

I've looked everywhere for a solution to this so I don't really expect it to be simple.

I want to display an icon with an overhead text label. I'd like the text to respond to hover, whether the cursor is positioned over the text OR over the icon image.

The closest example I can find is at this link http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?122028-Label-with-icon

which gives the following CSS solution:

> Label l = new Label("My Text");
>       l.addStyleName("my-label");
>
> ```
> #CSS
> .my-label {
> background:url(my-icon.png) no-repeat right center;
> padding-right:20px;
> }
> ```

But my CSS skills aren't good enough - I haven't had much success in adapting this to an above-centered label instead of a centered label to the left of the icon image.

Would anyone like to give it a shot for me?

---

Additional Info:

Here's what I have now - which isn't working, the `"display: block;` doesn't seem to let me use a `background-img` attribute ...

CSS:

```
 .blogicon {
    width: 70px;
    text-align: center;
    background-img:url("http://dispatchesusa.typepad.com/the_dov_blog/link-images/bookmark.png") no-repeat bottom center;
    display: block;
    padding-top: 4px;
    padding-bottom: 90px;
    }
```

HTML:

```
/* <h6 class="blogicon"><a href="/blog-index.html/">Blog</a></h6> */
```

Comment: You want to display the icon above the text?

Comment: No - text above the icon.

Comment: I changed my answer, have a look

Comment: Use `background:`. `background-img:` is not a CSS property. (It's `background-image:`, but here you don't want that, as you are using the background shorthand that includes other background properties.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be better if we could see your HTML, too, or at least a screen shot of what you are picturing, but this should be pretty easy. You can either wrap an `<a>` around the text and icon and set `:hover` rules, or you could add the text via the `:before` pseudo element to the `<a>`, which can be styled for both hover and non-hover states.

EDIT:

Now that we have a better idea of what you want, here's how you could do it:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">

<style media="all">
    .blogicon {
    width: 70px;
    text-align: center;
    backgrond: #f7f7f7;
    padding-top: 4px;
    }

    .blogicon a {
    display: block;
    background:url("http://dispatchesusa.typepad.com/the_dov_blog/link-images/bookmark.png") no-repeat 50% 100%;
    padding-bottom: 90px;
    color: blue;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: bold;
    }

    .blogicon a:hover, .blogicon a:focus {
        color: red;
    }
</style>

</head>
<body>

<div class="blogicon"><a href="/blog-index.html/">Blog</a></div>

</body>
</html>
```

I have taken the liberty to change `<h6>` to `<div>`, as this probably is not a true heading. But of course, you can change this back if you want, but it's rare to need an `<h6>`, so I suspect you are using it for presentational reasons, which is to be avoided. It's easy enough to set the font-weight of the link to bold, as shown.

Comment: `background-img` is not a CSS property. It's `background-image`.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to display the text above the icon, You can change the CSS to be:

```
.my-label {
    background:url(my-icon.png) no-repeat bottom center;
    padding-bottom:20px; /* this should be >= the icon's height */
}
```

Comment: OK - that puts the icon above the text. Almost there :)

Comment: the hover effect should be applied on both text or icon, isn't it?